# How to Evaluate $\int^\infty_0\int^\infty_0e^{-(x+y)^2} dx\ dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, transformation

How do you get from$$\int^\infty_0\int^\infty_0e^{-(x+y)^2} dx\ dy$$to
$$\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_0\int^u_{-u}e^{-u^2} dv\ du?$$ I have tried using a change of variables formula but to no avail.
Edit: Ok as suggested I set $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$, so I can see this gives $dx dy=\frac{1}{2}dudv$ but I still can't see how to get the new integration limits. Sorry if I'm being slow.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:   Try $u = x+y$, $v = x-y$

Comment: You'll want to read about the [Jacobian Transformation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Set $u=x+y$, $v=x-y$.

Then 
$$
\{(x,y): x,y\ge 0\}=\{(u,v) : u>0, v\in(-u,u)\},
$$
and
$$
dx\,dy=\frac{1}{2}du\,dv,
$$
as
$$
\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $x \equiv \rho\cos\pars{\theta}$, $y \equiv \rho\sin\pars{\theta}$ where $\rho \geq 0$ and $0 \leq \theta < 2\pi$ we'll get
$\ds{{\partial\pars{x,y} \over \partial\pars{\rho,\theta}} = \rho}$ such that

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#0000ff}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{x + y}^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y}
> =
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\rho^{2}\bracks{1 + \sin\pars{2\theta}}}\rho\,\dd\rho
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta\,\left.%
> {-\expo{-\rho^{2}\bracks{1 + \sin\pars{2\theta}}} \over 2\bracks{1 + \sin\pars{2\theta}}}
> \right\vert_{\rho = 0}^{\rho \to \infty}
> =
> \half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
> {\dd\theta \over 1 + \sin\pars{2\theta}}
> =
> {1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi}
> {\dd\theta \over 1 + \sin\pars{\theta}} = \color{#0000ff}{\large\half}
> \end{align}

since
\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over 1 + \sin\pars{\theta}}}
=\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over 1 + \sin\pars{\theta}}
=\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{1 - \sin\pars{\theta} \over \cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\\[3mm]&=
\half\,\lim_{\theta \to \pars{\pi/2}^{-}}\bracks{%
{\sin\pars{\theta} - 1 \over \cos\pars{\theta}}} + \half = \color{#0000ff}{\large\half}
\end{align}